# Tomcat receives HTTP 400 but CURL receives 200

Tags: java, sockets, curl, timeout

I have a very strange scenario where, in a Linux server, CURL successfully retrieves a response from a web service. When that same request is issued by Tomcat on the same linux server used for the CURL command, for some reason Tomcat receives a 400 status code, which prevents me from doing our business logic.

Flow with CURL:

- CURL issues request to Service A using Proxy A
- Service A retrieves the data we need and returns it, as well as a 200 Status Code
- CURL receives the correct data and 200 status code...

Flow with Tomcat:

- Tomcat  issues request to Service A using Proxy A
- Service A retrieves the data we need and returns it, as well as a 200 Status Code
- Tomcat receives a 400 status code and is not able to receive the correct data...

What could be causing this problem? Tomcat and CURL are using the same proxy and are in the same linux server... even the service is able to fetch the data successfully and return it to both. Only in the case of tomcat, the service is throwing this error after trying to write the data in the response:

```
2021-03-10 21:49:36.908  WARN 90623 --- [https-jsse-nio-8123-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException]
```

Tomcat closes the socket because it sees a 400 response code, and doesn't even try reading the bytes from the response when I do `con.getInputStream()`. I don't really know where that 400 Status code is coming from.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE 2021/03/11:**

One thing I forgot to mention is that, Tomcat is able to perform other requests to that same service. The main difference here is the size of the response. It timesout when trying to read this large response, in comparison to other smaller responses we get.

**UPDATE 2021/03/16:**

After investigating deeper on what is happening I found out that, whenever I issue the request with Java, for some reason it timesout at exactly 2 minutes. That doesn't happen with CURL, only with Java. Is there anything I may be missing? I have already added these to my code:

JVM Arguments:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=6000000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=6000000
```

Java code

```java
con.setReadTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
con.setConnectTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
```

I'm using an `HttpURLConnection` object.

Comment: Can you bump Tomcat's logging to debug mode and get in there and see what's going on?

Comment: I consume an HTTPS endpoint. After enabling the `javax.net.debug=ssl` flag for my request, I see these two exceptions: `javax.net.ssl|WARNING|21|https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3|2021-03-10 22:31:37.040 UTC|Logger.java:765|handling exception ("throwable":{  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)`

Comment: @RobertBain and `javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|21|https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3|2021-03-10 22:31:37.041 UTC|Logger.java:765|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Connection reset ("throwable" : { java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)`

Comment: @RobertBain, I added an update to the issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

The message that your tomcat sends to the service can not be read. Something happens with the message that your tomcat sends to the service. Does it have a json body included? If yes check that model class how it is serialized.

Comment: The service reads the message successfully... I see in the logs, the service is able to fetch the data I need. The problem happens when Tomcat tries to get an input stream and the response for the request.